# Programmatically creating a User Control in a Web Application project

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

In a **Web Site** Project, if I add a reference to a User Control to the markup of a page or control, as so:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/controls/myUserControl.ascx" %>
```

then I can programmatically create an instance of that control from the codebehind using the automatically-generated `ASP` namespace:

```
ASP.controls_myUserControl_ascx myControlInstance =
    new ASP.controls_myUserControl_ascx();
```

However, in a **Web Application** Project, I get a compilation error. [This comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/community/history/c0az2h86%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?id=7) on MSDN suggests that it just doesn't work in a Web Application Project, but doesn't suggest an alternative.

I can create an instance of the class which exists behind the user control as so:

```
MyWebApplication.controls.myUserControl myControlInstance
    = new MyWebApplication.controls.myUserControl();
```

but this doesn't include the markup (or any server-side controls) from the .ascx file, so this is no use.

I can instantiate a control including the markup as so:

```
MyWebApplication.controls.myUserControl myControlInstance
    = LoadControl("~/controls/myUserControl.ascx")
      as MyWebApplication.controls.myUserControl;
```

which lets me access all the properties and seems to work just fine. But, it seems a bit nasty to be loading the control from its string path when I could use a strongly-typed class in a different project type.

So, my question is: **is there a better way to programmatically create a User Control in a Web Application Project?** Or am I stuck with `LoadControl`?

Answer (score 0):

LoadControl is how you would programatically create a user control.